# Miss matched date after submission of form or post request

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, v-data-table

I have the following `date-picker` implementation

```
v-row>
                <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4" class="mr-12">
                      <v-menu
                        v-model="menu1"
                        :close-on-content-click="false"
                        transition="scale-transition"
                        offset-y
                        min-width="290px"
                      >
                        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                          <v-text-field
                            v-model="startDate"
                            label="Start Date"  
                            prepend-icon="event"
                            readonly
                            v-on="on"
                          ></v-text-field>
                        </template>
                        <v-date-picker v-model="startDate" no-title scrollable
                          @input="menu1 = false"
                        >
                        </v-date-picker>
                      </v-menu>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4" class="ml-12 pl-2">
                      <v-menu
                        v-model="menu2"
                        :close-on-content-click="false"
                        transition="scale-transition"
                        offset-y
                        min-width="290px"
                      >
                        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                          <v-text-field
                            v-model="endDate"
                            label="End Date"  
                            prepend-icon="event"
                            readonly
                            v-on="on"
                          ></v-text-field>
                        </template>
                        <v-date-picker v-model="endDate" no-title scrollable
                          @input="menu2 = false"
                        >
                        </v-date-picker>
                      </v-menu>
                </v-col>
              </v-row>

data () {
  return {
    startDate:null,
    endDate: null,
    menu1: false,
    menu2: false,
  }
```

[image: Left part is after post request i.e response, and console is the one before submitting]
I make post request for this data, but before submitting the data I have the correct format of the date but after submission I am getting miss matched format of the date. In the image Left part is after post request i.e response, and console is the one before submitting. Is this issue from backend ? I do not know the backend part.

Edit:

I tried formatting date in the following way:

```
format_date(date){
    const [, month, day, year] = date.split(' ')
    const ddMmmYyyy = [day, month, year].join('-')
    
    return ddMmmYyyy
```

This doesn't seems to work. Is this the correct way of formatting date ?

Comment: you receiveDateTime is a Date Object i guess. You will need to format to string in whatever way you like before sending to server. And the start and end date seems to be converted to DateTime object at backend. What backend are you using?

Comment: @HWSiew, my friend is using node in backend. Thank you for your response. Is the one I have added in edit part the correct way of formatting the date ?

Comment: Not really. First confirm your date is a Date object then you can refer https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp for methods available.